# Authentication in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: authentication, jquery-mobile, cordova, codeigniter-2

I have a web application built with jQuery Mobile and PHP (CodeIgniter framework). Now I'm trying to make a PhoneGap version of it as well, to make it distributable as a standalone app. However, the PHP web app. version uses Ion Auth, a CodeIgniter plugin for authentication. So when you go to a page that requires authentication, the app redirects you to the authentication controller login method. And after authentication it redirects you back to the home page (the jQuery Mobile page in this case). This works fine in the web app., since the home page is opened by the home controller in the first place anyway.

But here's the crux: in the PhoneGap version, the "home" page needs to be the index.html file in PhoneGap. Apparently you can load another url on startup by adding a value in PhoneGap.plist, but that is not acceptable by apple for submitting to app store. And if I do a redirect in the authentication, I can't get back to the index.html file after authentication...

So how should one go about authentication in a PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile app?

UPDATE:

I have tried this according to one of the answers, but the app still tries to navigate to the account/login page (which doesn't exist), when I just want to login through the post and return a value from the method:

```
    $('#login_form').bind('submit', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        //send a post request to your web-service
        $.post('http://localhost/app_xcode/account/login', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            //parse the response string into an object
            var response = response;
            //check if the authorization was successful or not
            if (response == true) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#toc', "slide");
            } else {
                alert('login failed');
                $.mobile.changePage('#toc', "slide");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here's the controller method:

```
function login()
    {
        //validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        $base_url = $this->config->item('base_url');

        $mobile = $this->detect_mobile();
        if ($mobile === false && $base_url != 'http://localhost/app_xcode/') //Only restrict if not developing
            redirect('account/notAMobile');

        else if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { //check to see if the user is logging in
            //check for "remember me"
            $remember = (bool)$this->input->post('remember');

            if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember)) { //if the login is successful
                //redirect them back to the home page
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());

                echo true;
                /*redirect($this->config->item('base_url'), 'refresh');*/
            }
            else
            { //if the login was un-successful
                //redirect them back to the login page
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                /*redirect('account/login', 'refresh');*/ //use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
            }
        }
        else
        { //the user is not logging in so display the login page
            //set the flash data error message if there is one
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors()
                    : $this->session->flashdata('message');

            $this->data['identity'] = array('name' => 'identity',
                                            'id' => 'identity',
                                            'type' => 'text',
                                            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
            );
            $this->data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
                                            'id' => 'password',
                                            'type' => 'password',
            );

        }
    }
```

I think I have removed or commented out any redirects that were there. So I don't know why it tries to load the view still? Does it have something to do with jQuery Mobile trying to navigate there because I post to that url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make requests to your web-service (Ion Auth) from your app. with jQuery. Your login would look something like this:

```
//add event handler to the `submit` event for your login form
$('#login_form').bind('submit', function () {

    //send a post request to your web-service
    $.post('http://my-domain.com/my-auth/auth.php', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {

        //parse the response string into an object
        response = $.parseJSON(response);

        //check if the authorization was successful or not
        if (response.status === 'success') {
            //do login here
        } else {
            //do error here
        }
    });
});
```

`$(this).serialize()` will add the login form's data to the post request. This example assumes your web-service will return JSON.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's actually not a web service really, it's just a plugin to CodeIgniter. I got something like your example working though. The only problem is that when I post to account/login (the login method in the account controller), it logs in, but it also ends up trying to navigate to a view account/login. I don't want that. I simply want to return a value (I echo one in the login method), but even though the value is returned it still tries to navigate to the login page too... See my update.

Comment: So people who see this in the future know, what was your solution?

Comment: For others wondering why it didn't work, it looks like function () was missing the variable.  It should be function (event) on the second line.

Comment: @Adam That's only true if you are attempting to use the `event` argument in your event handler, which the above example does not.

Comment: I guess I meant to comment on the authors code example, he used it there :)

Answer (score 5):

The reason your form is still submitting and it's trying to change pages is because you have a syntax error in your submit handler Javascript.  On line two, `event` is not defined so trying to call `event.preventDefault()` errors.  Although the handler fails, the browser still submits the form using it's default `action` and `method`.

Either change your function signature to `function(event) {` or simply return false from the function.  Returning `false` is equivalent to preventing default.

```
$('#login_form').bind('submit', function () {

    //send a post request to your web-service
    $.post('http://localhost/app_xcode/account/login', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        //check if the authorization was successful or not
        if (response == true) {
            $.mobile.changePage('#toc', "slide");
        } else {
            alert('login failed');
            $.mobile.changePage('#toc', "slide");
        }
    }, 'JSON');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Right, I actually figured it out myself and got it working. But thanks!

Comment: Watch-out for this: `response == true`. You're checking truthy/falsy values from a server-side script that could potentially send something you're not expecting (e.g. an error page rather than the expected output). I'd just recommend using `===` to make sure you get exactly what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at PhoneGap Plugin: [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) (iPhone, Android, other) and its locChanged method?

I have only coded apps that use OAuth ([Twitter App](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1)) and OpenID ([AppLaud App](https://github.com/paulb777/AppLaudApp)) for PhoneGap / Android, but the child browser plugin has what's needed for those. Sounds like Ion Auth may be similar: after auth driven by provider, return user to app seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. Not sure how to use it for this though... I have done almost no actual PhoneGap coding in this app (let alone XCode/Objective-C), only jQuery Mobile and html so I'm not sure what to do to achieve what I need.