# PhoneGap application and authentication against Domino server(xPages application ) - how to do it?

Tags: cordova, xpages

I'm working on a native mobile application using PhoneGap. Is there anyone with solution regarding the authentication? Specificaly, how to authenticate against the Domino server and keep the authentication in application? Can some share soltiuon or share some hint at least?

Thank you ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the others, here are some links on this topic in general:

[Authentication in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079459/authentication-in-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap)
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap
http://share.ez.no/blogs/thiago-campos-viana/rest-api-basic-http-auth-and-phonegap-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

A PhoneGap application is a web application running inside a native container so you should be able to use a normal logon page (optimized for mobile) and have the user logon using this.

After logon the user is authenticated with the Domino server.

The IBM Lotus iNotes Redirect template contains an example of a Domino logon page optimized for mobile.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how the PhoneGap works like, I have a mobile login page etc. but what I'm not sure is how to keep auth info on client side so for example my session authentication will not become timeouted, also every server restart or application restart removes all sessions from server so user is disconnected. I mean something like how my iPAD Evernote client works like, I did login just first time and never later ....

Comment: Then you need to store the user's id and password in the PhoneGap app and send a logon request in the background before the user accesses the Domino server. Have a look at the Dojo Login Custom Control on OpenNTF that sends a logon request through Ajax from a dialog: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control